# Class - Function Objects - PHP

Tags: php

I noticed on magento, they call a function which is referenced as an object like:

```
className::function('example')->example;
```

Which to me makes no sense how it works? I tried to mimic this inside a test file but I get nothing.

```
<?php

class Example
{

    public function test($arg)
    {
        $want = new ExampleTwo;
        return 1;
    }

}

class ExampleTwo
{
    public $want;
    public function urgh($arg)
    {
        $this->want = "returnn";
    }
}

$Obj = new Example;
echo $Obj->test('random')->want;
```

> NOTICE Trying to get property of non-object on line number 24

Can anyone please explain how the function becomes an Object? and if so, how can I then get values from the function object.

Comment: Function needs to return an object not a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you return an object in a function, you can call that object directly from the function returned value.

In your test case:

```
public function test($arg)
{
    $want = new ExampleTwo;
    return $want;
}
```

If you have this:

```
$Obj = new Example;
echo $Obj->test('random')->want
```

This will echo the "want" property of the ExampleTwo class, which will be NULL in your example code.

Comment: Wow, that actually makes more sense, I actually didn't know you could do this? That's awesome, you can even add functions and call functions `->anotherTest('?')->andAnother('ssss');` thats mad

Comment: this adds a whole new dimension to object orientated programming :o Appreciated!